# How open my toggle-accordion from another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the toggle-accordion. It works good if links and accordion there are on one page, url links works. But how make open my toggle-accordion to url from another page?

https://codepen.io/malinosky/pen/wxKzEo

```
$(function(){
var accordionFaqHead = $('.i-accordionFaq-head');

accordionFaqHead.on('click', function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});


function accHash() {
    var hash = $(this).attr('href'); 

    if (hash) {
        var accordionItem = $(hash);


        if (accordionItem.length) {
            accordionItem.find('.i-accordionFaq-body').show();
        }
    }
}

$('.i-link-hash').on('click', accHash);

});
```

Comment: Your question is totally unclear... what do you mean by "from another page"? You gave some working code and are asking about unclear thing...

Comment: Are you trying to create a link that when clicked would redirect to the page with the appropriate accordion already open?

Comment: Links "Link on first accordion" and "Link on second accordion" should be on another page. And when we click on link - should be open appropriate accordion. But if you do this, the code will not work

Comment: You have to store your accordion in a query param and get in the other page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there is `hash` in the `url` and call your function with it:

JS:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    var $hashedElement = $(window.location.hash);

    accHash.apply($hashedElement);
}
```

Use `apply` to call your function while setting `this` to be equal to `$hashedElement`

---

To add hash while going from page to page you need to add it to your anchor tag first:

HTML:

```
<a href="myotherpage.html#item1"></a>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/malinosky/pen/wxKzEo I'm add your code, but its not working. Why? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Well there isn't any `hash` in codepen. Try it out in real environment.

Comment: my mistake was in `var hash = $(this).attr('href');`. I've changed that to `hash = window.location.hash` and that works for me! Thank you!