# How to toggle accordion button from another page

Tags: html, jquery, css, toggle, accordion

I have an accordion menu in my website top page.
when click primary menus, accordion toggles using jQuery.
But when link to it from primary menus in another page, it doesn't work.

primary-menu

```
<ul id="menu-aaa" class="primary-menu">
<li id="menu-item-1">
<a href="toppage">home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2">
<a href="https://ccc/#aaa">aaa</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-3">
<a href="https://ccc/#bbb">bbb</a></li>
</ul>
```

accordion menu

```
<div id="aaa" class="testmenu">
<label for="testmenu_bar01"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="testmenu_bar01" class="accordion">
<ul id="links01">
    <li class="testmenu01-li-01"><a href="">link1</a></li>
    <li class="testmenu01-li-02"><a href="">link2</a></li>
    <li class="testmenu01-li-03"><a href="">link3</a></li>
    <li class="testmenu01-li-04"><a href="">link4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="bbb" class="testmenu">
<label for="testmenu_bar02"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="testmenu_bar02" class="accordion">
<ul id="links02">
    <li class="testmenu02-li-01"><a href="">link1</a></li>
    <li class="testmenu02-li-02"><a href="">link1</a></li>
    <li class="testmenu02-li-03"><a href="">link1</a></li>
    <li class="testmenu02-li-04"><a href="">link1</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function($){

    $("ul.primary-menu > li.menu-item-2 > a").click(function() {
        $('input#testmenu_bar01').prop('checked',true);
    })
       
    $("ul.primary-menu > li.menu-item-3 > a").click(function() {
        $('input#testmenu_bar02').prop('checked',true);
        $('li.testmenu01-li-02').css('margin-top','2vh');
    })

});
```

I read this
[How open my toggle-accordion from another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381825/how-open-my-toggle-accordion-from-another-page)
and I tried to add

```
$(location.hash).find(.accordion).prop('checked', true);
```

to my cord, but it was wrong.

Then, I tried this (in my wordpress site)

```
jQuery(function($){ 

  var url = $(window.location.href); 
  var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf('#'));
  $(hash).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
    
});
```

But it was something wrong, it doesn't work.

Comment: please add online result

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7z3Lhea/)
I couldn't reproduce jQuery.I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by use this jQuery code;

```
$(location.hash).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
```

Thank you.